# Sinatra with a Pure Ruby database

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I would like to use a pure ruby database (kirbybase http://www.netpromi.com/files/kirbybase_ruby_manual.html ) together with Sinatra so in ruby we would have something like this to display a record:

```
require 'kirbybase'
db = KirbyBase.new
cars_tbl= db.get_table(:cars)
ferrari = cars_tbl.select { |r| r.recno == 9 }
puts ferrari
```

or for all records

```
results = cars_tbl.select(:name,:race,:color,:recno).sort(+:color)
```

what would be the best way to integrate this with Sinatra without obfuscating the "rubysh "kirbybase syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To take a leaf about of [sinatra-redis](https://github.com/bmizerany/sinatra-redis/)'s book, you can do something like this:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'kirbybase'

helpers do
  # Create a helper to allow easier access to settings.kirby
  # Name it whatever you want
  def kirby
    settings.kirby
  end
end

configure do
  # Initialise kirby
  set :kirby, KirbyBase.new
end

get '/' do
  cars_tbl = kirby.get_table(:cars)
  ferrari = cars_tbl.select { |r| r.recno == 9 }
  "Car is #{ferrari}"
end
```

Comment: thanks for this but it returns an error server:Sites devnull$ ruby sinatrakb.rb 
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1197:in `define_method': tried to create Proc object without a block (ArgumentError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1197:in `generate_method'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1206:in `compile!'

Comment: it works but on your last bit it should be get '/' do :) appreciated your kind help ! wow this was easy :) gotta love Sinatra :) is there any easy way to embed kirbybase in a gem to include both sinatra and the db engine by default ?

Comment: Oops! That's what you get for not testing your code... I'll edit it.

I'm not quite sure what you mean I'm afraid. Include Sinatra and the db engine into where?

Comment: Hi !
thanks for this I mean creating a new gem that would not require include kirbybase but would be already embedded and ready to use/be called when needed

Comment: Sorry, it's still not clear. A gem that's embedded in something? Are you looking to use KirbyBase without requiring it? What would this gem do?

Comment: well simply a gem with both kirbybase and sinatra like many others that include sinatra and another database ..this might also allow to run sinatra without a require kirbybase